# Lemmas / proofs about subtyping judgments

Tags: fstar

There are times when subtyping judgments are too difficult for f-star to figure out automatically, and f-star would like me to spell out my proofs in more detail. I am also running into cases where I would like to write a lemma that just proves f-star can make some type judgment.

A piece of syntax that looks like it does this does parse, but it seems to not do what I want. I suspect I misunderstand what this syntax does. Here I am trying to just prove that x has type nat with a Lemma. Why doesn't this do what I think it does?

```
let x: nat = 3
val tj_lem: unit -> Lemma (x: nat)
let tj_lem () = ()
```

I am also surprised that I can write "x: nat" in that position. How can I "prove that x is a nat" if I needed to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've hit an ugly corner of F*'s syntax.
https://github.com/FStarLang/FStar/issues/1905
We've been discussing ways to improve it.

In particular, F* allows you to associate names with types that are in some cases meaningless. In your example the name `x` is meaningless in the `x:nat` that appears in the type of Lemma. It is interpreted by F* as `unit -> Lemma nat`: this is the type of a proof that shows that the `nat` type is inhabited … which isn't particularly interesting. For the record, one way to prove that uninteresting type is

```
let nat_is_inhabited () : Lemma nat = FStar.Squash.return_squash #nat 0
```

Now, to your actual question of how to spell out a proof of subtyping. There are many ways. One common way is as follows:

Let's say you have the type

```
let tp = x:t { p }
```

And at some point you have

```
let f (x:t) = … assert (q x); let y : tp = x in …
```

i.e., because of some contextual information that gives you the property `q x`, you want to treat `x:t` at the type `tp`.

If you can prove a lemma of the form

```
val q_implies_p (x:t) : Lemma (requires q x) (ensures p x)
```

then by calling the lemma at the right point in your code, you can give F* and the SMT solver enough information to accept the subtyping of `x:t` to `tp`. For example, something like this:

```
let f (x:t) = … assert (q x); q_implies_p x; let y : tp = x in …
```

Hope that helps. Sorry about the confusing syntax!

Comment: No worries about the syntax. I appreciate your thorough and prompt reply! (I meant to write thanks earlier).